# Becoming Bar Mitzvah on Shabbas but made early kiddush

Tags: shabbat, kiddush, bar-bas-bat-mitzvah

A child once they become Bar/Bas Mitzvah is now an adult and is obligated in all the mitzvos (assuming they've reached physical maturity). In the case where they became Bar Mitzvah on Shabbas (Friday night after dark), if the family took Shabbas in early and made Kiddush before dark, after dark is the Bar Mitzvah obligated (or even permitted) to repeat Kiddush?

In other words, was the Kiddush that was made for them before dark considered a דרבנן, and now they are obligated מן התורה? What about the brachos, as those are only דרבנן? What is the solution to this situation? (Besides finding another family who hasn't said Kiddush yet to be motzi).

The Mishnah Berurah addresses taking shabbas in early not working to make a child an adult, so that's not a solution.

> משנה ברורה סימן נ"ג סקל"ג
>
> במקומות שנוהגין להתפלל של שבת בע"ש מבעוד יום משום תוספת שבת מ"מ הרי עדיין לא נשלמו לו י"ג שנה עד ליל שבת שתוספת שבת אינו מועיל לענין שנות ימי הנער

Comment: Kiddush Min HaTorah is fulfilled by Davening (accd to most opinions). Surely the kid will Daven on Shabbat itself, so what is your issue? I don't see what the big deal is about the Kos, if that's what you are asking about. It's no different than saying Birkhot Keriat Shema before dark, for instance.

Comment: He already davened before dark, and מצוות צריכות כוונה. You're suggesting when he davens in the morning he should have in mind to be yotzi? And yes there's issues with the kos. You're not allowed to eat before making kiddush. You're obligated to make Kiddush on a kos, has he fulfilled these requirements or since he's now an adult his old Kiddush wasn't sufficient. I don't see the relevance to Birkos Krias Shema, that's דרבנן and can be fulfilled before dark. Here he was a double דרבן, since he was a child. Now it's a single דרבן.

Comment: "that's דרבנן and can be fulfilled before dark." Kiddush on a Kos is the _exact same thing_.

Comment: Re מצוות צריכות כוונה: there's plenty of discussion about fulfilling Kiddush with Davening. It's basically assumed in discussions of being Motzi one's wife who didn't Daven etc. Yet no one I know of has explicit Kavana at Maariv to be Yotzei Kiddush. They have Kavana to say Maariv and it works. There's no reason Shacharit/Musaf/Mincha would be different.

Comment: Re: Kiddush with davening, yes there are those that say you are yotzi, but the משנה ברורה says you're not without kavannah, like you said otherwise you couldn't be motzi one's wife

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45982/discussion-between-robev-and-double-aa).

Comment: This question is dealt with at great length, by Rabbi Nosson Gestetner z"l, in his work,  Shut Le'horos Nossan. שו"ת להורות נתן (Volume 7, No. 13-14) https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=934&st=&pgnum=29&hilite=

Comment: The same shaila if he needs new birkas hatorah.. kiddush levana.

Comment: @Shlomy I've heard re: birchas hatorah that they should daven maariv asap (and then learn something?) so they're covered by birchas krias shema.

Answer (score 2):

I asked this question to **Rav Zev Leff** and he said (as pointed out in the comments) that there are many examples of someone fulfilling something as a child and then becoming bar mitzvah. One example he gave is they ate a meal and said *birkas hamazon*, and when they became an adult they were still satiated. Do they say it again?

He said, based on the fact that a child who eats the *korbon Pesach* with their family, and then becomes an adult before Pesach Sheni, is exempt from Pesach Sheni, that we don't say they become obligated again. They wouldn't have to say *birkas hamazon* again and in this case would not need to make *kiddush* again. I still have to investigate the reason and source for the *korbon Pesach* though.

Comment: In those cases the obligation took effect while he was a child. Here there was no adult to accept shabbos early, so he arguably becomes obligated with nightfall.

Answer (score -4):

This happened to me. I had to say kiddush again in the middle of the meal when it was dark

Comment: Did a Halakhic decisor instruct you to do this? Who? Do you know their reasoning?